# convert one derived class to another?

Tags: vb.net, class, oop, inheritance

I have one class 'timerecord' and two classes 'stopwatch' and 'historic' which inherit from this class but do not extend it with any additional properties or methods. Their constructors simply set the inherited properties to different things.

What I want to be able to do is convert one type of the inherited classes into the other type( without manually copying all of the properties from the one into the other)

I've tried all types of ctype and directcast statements but they do not work, I can only cast back to the inherited class and that is not what I want.

The classes are identical in all but their name.
I want the stopwatch object to turn into a historic object..

Is there a way that I can do this?

If I implement the 'timerecord' class as well as inherit?  Or pass a 'timerecord' into the 'stopwatch' and 'historic' classes constructors and have it as a property or something?

Have been scratching my head about this all day and decided to make an account and ask as I cannot seem to find the answer.

Tldr; I want to know how to convert one derived class to another identical(in all but name) derived class, and if it is even possible?

Thank you

Comment: if they are identical, why not just a `TypeCode` property to distinguish one from another?  Converting would then just be a matter of changing the code.  Otherwise a ctor overload which takes the other type would allow you to create one from the other.

Comment: @Jowijaro : add code example to your question !!!

Answer (score 0):

If the properties are the same, you could serialize your instance of `stopwatch` into a string then deserialize it into your `historic` instance.

However, I think the best solution would be to have only a `timerecord` class with an enum type property that would use to have a distinction between a `stopwatch` and an `historic` instance.  That way, you could pass the timerecord type enum to your constructor and set the property the way you need them depending on the enum value.

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to use an enum and initialize based on it.  If the only constructor requires it, one or the other would always has to be created.

```
Friend Enum TimeRecordTypes
    Undefined
    StopWatch
    Historic
End Enum

Public Class TimeRecord
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Foo As Integer 
    Public Property Bar As DateTime

    Public ReadOnly Property TimeRecordType As TimeRecordTypes = Undefined
    ...

    Public Sub New(e As TimeRecordTypes)
        Select Case e
            Case TimeRecordTypes.StopWatch
               do stopwatch stuff
            Case TimeRecordTypes.Historic
               do Historic stuff

         End Select 
    End Sub

    Public Sub ConvertTo(maybe an arg for the type)
       ' convert A to B
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

"*(without manually copying all of the properties from the one into the other)*"

Really ?
I think that at a point or another, you'll have to write more complex code doing this...

Serialize/Deserialize... handy way most of the time. I used this.. until I added a Property in a class without adding their counterparts in the fellow ones. Classes like `Point2D` with X and Y as double, `Vector2D` with X and Y as double or `Displacement2D` with X and Y as double... until I added the property `Length` in Vector2D... and later, `Distance` in Displacement2D.. :/

A property (enum) defining the type of the object. Same here : At a point or another, for the ease of usage, you *may* add members to one of the classes that has nothing to do in the others. :/ That makes your objects, either unable to grow/evolve, either weird with non used/fake members...

So in the end, I think you'll have to choose between "frozing" your classes at their current state (members) or writing each required code handling the conversion, and updating those whenever it's required (adding/editing a member)

---

What about Widening with CType ?

```
Public Class StopWatch
    Inherits TimeRecord

    ' ...

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal HistoricInstance As Historic) As StopWatch
        Dim NewStopWatch As StopWatch
        If HistoricInstance IsNot Nothing Then
            NewStopWatch = New StopWatch(...)
            ' Set NewStopWatch Properties here...
            ' ...
            Return NewStopWatch
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Operator
End Class
```

And :

```
Public Class Historic
    Inherits TimeRecord

    ' ...

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal StopWatchInstance As StopWatch) As Historic
        Dim NewHistoric As Historic
        If StopWatchInstance IsNot Nothing Then
            NewHistoric = New Historic(...)
            ' Set NewHistoric Properties here...
            ' ...
            Return NewHistoric
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Operator
End Class
```

Note : If you add a Property to StopWatch, but not to Historic, the StopWatch CType operator becomes a Narrowing one instead of a Widening.

Of course, this will create a new instance of the class everytime you cast one class to another.. Sometimes, this is not handy when you want both classes use the same contained object (not a new instance of) and months later, you've forgotten you've coded the widening operator in a way to create new instances of all the members...

Suppose you have a class MyStopWatch of type StopWatch, and a property InitializationDateTime that is set to Date.Now in the constructor..

```
MyStopWatch = New StopWatch() ' .InitializationDateTime = Date.Now
' do some stuff...
MyHistoric = CType(MyStopWatch, Historic) ' where MyHistoric.InitializationDateTime = Date.Now
```

With the above code, you'll have different values of the property InitializationDateTime even if you assume you've correctly casted MyTimeRecord to MyHistoric, this, due to the fact that CType created an instance of Historic at a *later* time than when MyTimeRecord has been initialized.

So how ? Serialization, TypeCode Property/Enum or CType Widening ?

Plutonix has another way :

```
Public Class StopWatch()
    Public Sub New(ByVal HistoricInstance As Historic)
        ' Copy Properties values here...
    End Sub
End Class
' Do the same for Historic Class.
```

Or you can also make functions (VB.net meaning)

```
Public Class StopWatch()
    Public Function ToHistoric() As Historic
        Dim NewHistoric As New Historic()
        ' .. set NewHistoric Properties values here
        Return NewHistoric
    End Function
End Class
```

But the result is the same : you'll have to write code to set the properties values one by one. The good thing is : you write the code once, eventually update it, but you can use it anytime with just one line of code...

`DirectCast` is handy, but prone to runtime crash.
`TryCast` is funny, but you'll have to check the failure of casting anyway. :/

There's still other ways to do it, but from now, does one of the proposed way is usefull enough or you have some specific requirements, like the issue above ?

Comment: The widening seems like it is going to work for me. For reasons beyond my control, the system I am working with used two collections of the same type. 
One collection stored current stopwatches, and the other stored the historic. The only distinction between the types is the collection they are in.
To change this I wanted to have a single keyedCollection of the base type, and create a derived type which I specify to add to the collection, instead of a single generic type.

Comment: The difficulty came when I needed to replicate the moving from 'stopwatch' to 'historic' definitions of 'timerecord'. As this was previously done by removing an item from the stopwatch collection to the historic collection I figured that in my collection I would be able to just convert the one type to the other. The Widening conversion will allow me to do this

Comment: I can now have a 'stopwatch' type, which can be converted to a 'historic' type when it gets old, just as it did in the old system. But this way I only use one strongly typed collection, and can use Inheritance to separate the types, it makes the code a lot cleaner and easier to understand what is being created and also makes it easier for me to maintain, and is actually a lot less code than the original. Thank you.

Comment: The only bad thing is that I still have to set the properties of the new object one at a time in the widening operation. But i guess that's just being lazy, and the benefit of being able to say ctype(mystopwatch, historic) and having it all happen in there is a lot neater than having to create a new historic item and copy values into its properties each time i needed one. Besides, im sure a loop to copy the properties of one to the other will be easy enough using reflection. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I had tried the solutions provided and in doing so came to realise that the solution is not using inheritance, but instead, as they are exactly the same but with different names, to use an Interface.
I created an interface and also another class 'basetimerecord', all three classes implement this interface.
The basetimerecord's properties point to variables.

The other classes properties point to the properties of a private variable of type basetimerecord.
The basetimerecord is exposed through a public read only property.
The constructors of each of these classes can take a basetimerecord as a parameter. When they do, they override their own private variable with it, thus I can copy all the properties by only changing one private variable each time.

I can now do historic = new historic(stopwatch.basetimerecord)